# Passing values to a command

Tags: macros, loops

I am new to Tikz and have been largely following the PGFManual to learn about how to use it correctly. The PGFManual shows examples of using `foreach` but they do not show how to pass it to a command. The code I am writing populates space with tetrahedra to define a pyrochlore lattice. I declare commands to draw a tetrahedron given a specific coordinate.

```
\newcommand{\tetra}[4]{
    \coordinate (A#1) at (#2+0.00,#3+0.00,#4+0.00);
    \coordinate (B#1) at (#2+0.00,#3+0.25,#4+0.25);
    \coordinate (C#1) at (#2+0.25,#3+0.00,#4+0.25);
    \coordinate (D#1) at (#2+0.25,#3+0.25,#4+0.00);
}

\newcommand{\drawtetra}[1]{
    \draw[lf line, opacity=1] (A#1)--(B#1)--(C#1)--cycle;
    \draw[df line, opacity=1] (A#1)--(B#1)--(D#1)--cycle;
}
```

and then call them in the document to print out my desired tetrahedra

```
\tetra{1}{0.00}{0.00}{0.00}
\tetra{2}{0.00}{0.50}{0.50}
\tetra{3}{0.50}{0.00}{0.50}
\tetra{4}{0.50}{0.50}{0.00}

\drawtetra{1}
\drawtetra{2}
\drawtetra{3}
\drawtetra{4}
```

I would like to automate the process by doing something like

```
foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \drawtetra{\i}
```

This gives a slew of errors that mostly have to do with `endcsname`

I have not found any solution for this online although the closest relation I could find used `pgfkeys` unfortunately I was unable to relate it back to my own program. Any help would be appreciated. The complete code to generate the image is given below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %mentioned by Kevin C in comments
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  %mentioned by Kevin C in comments

\newcommand{\tetra}[4]{
  \coordinate (A#1) at (#2+0.00,#3+0.00,#4+0.00);
  \coordinate (B#1) at (#2+0.00,#3+0.25,#4+0.25);
  \coordinate (C#1) at (#2+0.25,#3+0.00,#4+0.25);
  \coordinate (D#1) at (#2+0.25,#3+0.25,#4+0.00);
}

\newcommand{\drawtetra}[1]{
  \draw[lf line, opacity=1] (A#1)--(B#1)--(C#1)--cycle;
  \draw[df line, opacity=1] (A#1)--(B#1)--(D#1)--cycle;
}

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{70}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale = 12,
    axis/.style={very thick, ->, >=stealth'},
    df line/.style={thick, fill=darkgray!60, opacity=1},  %darkface
    lf line/.style={thick, fill=gray!30, opacity=1},      %lightface
    tdplot_main_coords
    ]

    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);

    \tetra{1}{0.00}{0.00}{0.00}
    \tetra{2}{0.00}{0.50}{0.50}
    \tetra{3}{0.50}{0.00}{0.50}
    \tetra{4}{0.50}{0.50}{0.00}

    \drawtetra{1}
    \drawtetra{2}
    \drawtetra{3}
    \drawtetra{4}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code compiles if you add `\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}` (instead of `\usepackage{3dplot}`) and `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}`. But I don't know if the result is what you wanted

Comment: Thank you for the notice.

Mine won't compile when I use the \usepackage{tikz-3dplot} instead of \usepackage{3dplot} but I assume this is because the folder was named 3dplot after the extraction. Oddly enough tough I do not need arrows.

However since others will not be able to compile I shall change them as you suggested. 

Once again, thank you for the notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were just missing a semicolon. Semicolons are very important in TikZ. In fact, one could say that TikZ is less like LaTeX and more like C or Java in this respect. The following works:

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,4} 
  \drawtetra\i;
```

You could alternately use a group, then you don't need the semicolon.

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,4} { 
  \drawtetra\i
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much for pointing this out.